# How to turn off a USB drive when samba is not using it [Raspberry PI]

Tags: usb, samba, usb-drive, raspbian

I have a backup server on a Raspberry Pi using samba with 2x 2TB drives for storage. To reduce noise and drive degradation I'd like to turn them off when I'm not transferring files.

I tried to unmount it but the disck kept spinning. I also tried "echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level - error "no such file or directory".

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried to unmount it It didn't change anything. I also tried "echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level - error "no such file or directory".

Comment: please add your comment to the question @user61143